# Does GetComponent<T>() work on T extended classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm develloping a game for last under-graduate year with a team of 3 people.

#### Class and script

---

Some one has make 3 scripts :

- MinerController.cs
- PlayerController.cs
- PlayerPhysic.cs

`MinerController` extend MonoBehavior
`PlayerController` extend MinerController
`PlayerPhysic` extend MonoBehavior

#### Exemple and question

---

If I attach `PlayerController.cs` and `PlayerPhysic.cs` to my gameObject and do this inside `PlayerPhysic.cs` :

```
public void Awake()
{
    minerController = GetComponent<MinerController>();
}
```

would i get a `null` or `PlayerController` and why it behave like that ?

Comment: Perhaps try it and find out?

Comment: You will get null if this object, attached with PlayerController component, doesnot have MinerController. If it has MinerController component, it will be not null. Take a look at documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: @Kamiky I wouldn't reference the russian page of an out-of-date Unity version ;) rather use the [latest API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html)

Comment: @Kamiky Also, you're wrong. There *is* a `MinerController` component attached: `PlayerController extends MinerController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works since `PlayerController` is of type `MinerController` or better said it is derived from it.

It is the same way e.g. `GetComponent<Collider>` works on any type deriving from [`Collider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) or `GetComponent<Renderer>` works on any type deriving from [`Renderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.html).

Though both are abstract parent classes that cannot be attach themselves only their explicit implementations like `BoxCollider` or `MeshRenderer`.

---

So yes you will get the `PlayerController` or any other component of type `MinerController` that is attached to that GameObject. `null` if there was none found.

To answer your title: No!
It works not for just any `T` but any class type deriving from [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) but of course you would get a compiler error anyway if you tried to use any type not deriving from `Component`.